# GCC fails to link to libc.a

Tags: c, gcc, libc

I am compiling a project with multiple libraries without issue.  I am using stdlib content.  However, `math.h` functions are failing to link.  My command line compilation is as follows:

```
gcc -o exe/split main/split.c -I/usr/include/gsl  -Isrc -Llib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -ltools -lgsl
```

I am compiling this simple script and just now added `sqrt` from `math.h` amidst many gsl functions that compile and work fine.  `libc.a` exists at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

At this point, the failure to link is odd enough that I am essentially stuck.  What could be the problem here?

Comment: append ```-lm``` to your compilation command line. libm is the math library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most functions declared in `<math.h>` actually aren't in libc. They're in libm, for hysterical raisins - I mean, historical reasons.

Add "`-lm`" to your command line. It's probably best to put it at the very end.